# I'm trying to prove the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ using geometry.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ using geometry.

So far I've created a square with area $x$ and side lengths $\sqrt{x}$.

The derivative of the function is $\frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx}$  with $dx$ being the increase in area.

I've set up the equations for the change in f,

$df = 2(\sqrt{x})(\text{ }d\sqrt{x})\text{  }+\text{  }d\sqrt{x}\text{  }d\sqrt{x}$

$df = 2(\sqrt{x})(\text{ }d\sqrt{x})\text{  }+\text{  }dx$

I'm supposed to wind up with $\frac{df}{dx}$ = $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

What I end up getting is $\frac{df}{dx}$ = $\frac{1}{1-2\sqrt{x}}$

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How come $d\sqrt{x}d\sqrt{x}=dx$?

Comment: What is $f$? ......

Comment: I assumed that since $dx*dx = dx^{2}$

Comment: $f$ is $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=3

Comment: 12:31 of the video I've linked

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you simplified $\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)^2$ as $\mathrm dx$. You're squaring the entire differential, not the function within it. Now, all you need to consider is that as $\mathrm d\sqrt{x} \to 0$, $\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)^2 \to 0$ much faster. So, you have

$$\mathrm dx = 2(\sqrt{x})\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)+\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right) = 2(\sqrt{x})\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)+\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)^2$$

This means $\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)^2$ is negligible, leaving you with the desired result:

$$\mathrm dx = 2(\sqrt{x})\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right) \iff \frac{\mathrm d\sqrt{x}}{\mathrm dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by KM101 is spot on, I think the mistake Andrew is making is much deeper.
 Having watched this particular video by 3B1B myself, I can see where Andrew's solution goes wrong:
Consider the initial example in the video - how to find the derivative of $x^2$. The area of the sqaure he has constructed is $x^2$, with the sides as x. Hence, your **f** is $x^2$. The change in area you find is **df** or **d($x^2$)**. 
In this case however, **$\sqrt{x}$ *  $\sqrt{x}$** is the **f**. Or in other words, *x* is the *f*. So, change in area is equal to **d($\sqrt{x} * \sqrt{x}$)** or **dx**. 
And then as KM101 has written, 
$df = dx =2(\sqrt{x})(d\sqrt{x}) + (d\sqrt{x})^2$
Ignoring $(d\sqrt{x})^2$ as it evaluates to be too small, 
$dx = 2(\sqrt{x})(d\sqrt{x}) \implies \frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, 
which is what you wanted to find in the first place - the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ with respect to x.
Hope that helps!

Comment: The video it great, recommend to anyone learning Calculus!