# Derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ using geometry

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble with a problem given in a video by 3Blue1Brown, to which I have already found a response, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418509/im-trying-to-prove-the-derivative-of-sqrtx-using-geometry/3598735#3598735).

My is issue is understanding *why* the equation $$\mathrm dx = 2(\sqrt{x})\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)+\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right) = 2(\sqrt{x})\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)+\left(\mathrm d\sqrt{x}\right)^2$$ was assembled (in the above thread).

In the video, he does say dx = "New area" and by calculating "New area" I did reach to the same equation. My lack of understanding is why dx is regarded as the new area.

[Link](https://youtu.be/S0_qX4VJhMQ?t=754) to the problem in the video.

Thanks :)

Comment: These are two terms of a quadratic trinomial ($\sqrt x^2$ dropped.)

Answer (score 1):

Change the area of a square from $A$ to $A+dA$. At the same time, the side varies from $S$ to $S+\Delta S$ and

$$(A+\Delta A)-A=(S+\Delta S)^2-S^2=2S\,\Delta S+\Delta S^2.$$

Hence

$$\frac{\Delta S}{\Delta A}=\frac1{2S+\Delta S}\approx\frac1{2S}=\frac1{2\sqrt A}$$ as the term $\Delta S$ is made negligible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the initial example in the video - how to find the derivative of $x^2$. The area of the sqaure he has constructed is $x^2$, with the sides as x. Hence, your **f** is $x^2$. The change in area you find is **df** or **d($x^2$)**. 
3B1B wants you take a slightly different approach here and create a square with sides as **$\sqrt{x}$**.

In this case however, **$\sqrt{x}$ *  $\sqrt{x}$** is the **f**. Or in other words, *x* is the *f*. So, change in area is equal to **d($\sqrt{x} * \sqrt{x}$)** or **dx**. 
And then change in area is, 
$df = dx =2(\sqrt{x})(d\sqrt{x}) + (d\sqrt{x})^2$
Ignoring $(d\sqrt{x})^2$ as it evaluates to be too small, 
$dx = 2(\sqrt{x})(d\sqrt{x}) \implies \frac{d\sqrt{x}}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$, 
which is what you wanted to find in the first place - the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ with respect to x.
Hope that helps!