# Finding the derivative of $\sqrt x$ geometrically

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

I've been smacking my head against a wall on this for a couple hours now.

Here is a square, it as an area of **x** and a side length of **√x** . If the side length increases by some **dx**, what is the corresponding change in area aka **df**
Drawing of the square and subsequent calculations:
[image: Drawing of the square and subsequent calculations]

The expected answer is

$$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

I have tried to intuitively reason my way out of this.

**df** is the increase area for a given **dx** as **dx** approaches 0. Therefore the areas of the two rectangles plus the small square is equal to **df**.

Area of the two rectangles
$$2\sqrt{x} \cdot dx$$

Area of the small square
$$dx^2$$

Therefore **df** being the total area of the increase is
$$2\sqrt{x} \cdot dx + dx^2$$

We discount the addition of $dx^2$ because it is of negligible size. And that leaves us with the rate of increase of **df** per **dx**

$$\frac{df}{dx} = \frac{2\sqrt{x} \cdot dx}{dx}$$
$$\frac{df}{dx} = 2\sqrt{x}$$

Where have I gone wrong? I feel like it's something obvious...

Thank you in advance.

Related Question:

[I'm trying to prove the derivative of $\sqrt{x}$ using geometry.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3418509/im-trying-to-prove-the-derivative-of-sqrtx-using-geometry)

Helpful Youtube video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0_qX4VJhMQ&list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr&index=4

Comment: Not that I can make sense of any of this anyways, but why is the small side $dx$? You want to differentiate with respect to the area ($\frac d{df}$? Or is it $\frac d{dx}$? You don't seem to be consistent in this regard), so if anything it should be $d\sqrt x$ or $d\sqrt f$.

Comment: Um. You are describing the change in $\sqrt x$ in terms of changes in $x$.  You are describing the changes in $x$ in terms of changes in $\sqrt x$.  In other words instead of calculating $\frac {d\sqrt x}{dx}$ (which one expects to be $\frac 1{2\sqrt x}$) you are calculating $\frac {dx}{d\sqrt x}$ which one expects and you seem to have found to be $2\sqrt x$.

Comment: As the area is $x$, the change in area should be $dx$. As the side length is $\sqrt x$, the change in side length should be $d\sqrt x$. These are the $dx$ and $d\sqrt x$ in $\frac{d\sqrt x}{dx}$.

Comment: Ah I see where I went wrong. Thank you all!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The area of the square is $x$

Then we increase the area of the square to $x+\Delta x$

[image]

The red area is $\Delta x$

The thickness of the red bars is $\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt {x}$
The length of the red bars is $\sim\sqrt x$

$2(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt {x})\sqrt x \approx \Delta x$

$\frac {(\sqrt{x+\Delta x} - \sqrt {x})}{\Delta x} \approx \frac {1}{2\sqrt x}$

And at the limit, they are equal.

Comment: Thank you! That is very clear now.